# Mysql_fetch_array( $result, MYSQL_BOTH ) is not exact

Tags: mysql

I have a weird problem with `mysql_fetch_array( $result , MYSQL_BOTH )`. This is how the problem is reproduced:

1. Do a query string that uses `LEFT JOIN`, `GROUP BY`

```sql
    select *, 
           (A1.total - A2.borrow_total) as remain_total 
      from ( select Min(sample_created_date) as created_date, 
             sample_model,
             sample_ncc, 
             count(*) as total , 
             sample_sort 
              from tb_sample 
             where 1=1 
               AND sample_kho IN ( 'hanoi','tm_hanoi' ) 
             group by sample_model, sample_sort, sample_ncc 
           ) A1 left join 
           ( select sample_model as sample_model1, 
                    count(*) as borrow_total, 
                    sample_ncc 
               from tb_sample B1 left join tb_sample_ticket B2 
                 on B1.sample_borrow_status = B2.ticket_id 
              where 1=1 
                and ticket_bo_phan_duyet = 'finish' 
                and ticket_status_duyet = '1' 
                AND sample_kho IN ( 'hanoi','tm_hanoi' ) 
              group by sample_model, sample_ncc 
            ) A2 on A1.sample_model = A2.sample_model1 
                AND A1.sample_ncc = A2.sample_ncc left join tb_product_sort A3 
                 on A1.sample_sort = A3.sort_code 
    where 1=1 
    order by created_date DESC 
    LIMIT 0, 30
```

1. Implement `mysql_fetch_array( $result , MYSQL_BOTH )`:

   ```
   $rw  = mysql_fetch_array( $result , MYSQL_BOTH );
   ```
2. Display value of `$rw`:

   ```
   echo  $rw['sample_cc'];
   ```

But there is nothing. Then I try `print_r( $rw )`, see below for the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2013-06-13 04:10:39
    [created_date] => 2013-06-13 04:10:39
    [1] => 3G
    [sample_model] => 3G
    **[2] => Gmobile
    [sample_ncc] =>** 
    [3] => 1
    [total] => 1
    [4] => SIM
    [sample_sort] => SIM      
);
```

I see that **`$Rw[2] = 3G`** but **`$rw['sample_ncc'] is null`**.

This is a weird problem. Please help me solve it.

Comment: Show your query. It looks like you have more than one column with the same name.

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: @peterm: I just share my query.

Comment: Dear Peterm, this bug solved. you right, there is more than one column with same name. Thansk to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to give explicit aliases for `sample_ncc` columns in subqueries `A1` and `A2` (e.g. `sample_ncc_a1` and `sample_ncc_a2`) or return only one that is on the left side of `LEFT JOIN` (meaning in `A1`).